# How to save SharePoint Site Page as PDF and save PDF to document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I would like to know if it is possible to automate the process of saving a SharePoint site page as a pdf and then saving this pdf into a document library. Currently to do this I have to print the page (ctrl+p) and choose the option to save as pdf. Then once saved to my pc I upload the pdf file to the document library. Is it possible to have a webpart or button on the site page, which automatically does this for me using custom code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **OneDrive** and **MS Flow** to realize your design.

**Please follwo steps:**

1. Use shortcut keys：**Ctrl + P** to save SharePoint Site Page as PDF

[image]

2. Click **Print** and save print output as **OneDrive Sync Field**

- Note: In my environment, OneDrive has been synchronized with File Explorer in Windows
- More information, please refer to [Sync files with OneDrive in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-files-with-onedrive-in-windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49).

[image]

3. Sign in **OneDrive Online**, click **Automate** menu, and then select **Power Automate** to create a flow

[image]

4. **Create a flow:**

- Add a Trigger "**When a file is created (OneDrive)**"
- Add anAction "**Create file (SharePoint)**"
- Add anAction "**Delete file (OneDrive)**"
  [image]

5. Save and Test this flow

[image]